# Creating a directory in Ruby ENOENT Error

Tags: ruby

I'm very new in Ruby. I'm trying to create a Directory, this way:

```
d = Dir.new("somedir")
```

but I get back this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - somedir
from (irb):12:in `initialize'
from (irb):12:in `new'
from (irb):12
from /Users/Estimanol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I've been looking at other entries and they said it's because you're in the same directory you're creating at, but that's not my case. If I enter

```
Dir.chdir ("..")
```

Keeps telling me the same error, but wherever I am if I enter

```
d= Dir.new(".")
```

It allows me to create the directory. Could be because of the permissions?
Don't know why, could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a directory, you can use :

```
Dir.mkdir("somedir")
```

`Dir.new` tries to create a new Ruby Object (an instance of the Dir class), related to the directory called `somedir`. If there is no such directory, you get the error you mentioned in your question. `Dir.new` does not try to create the corresponding directory.

If you want to create multiple directories inside one another, you can use :

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkpath("somedir/subfolder/another_subfolder")
```

If you want to get a Dir object for the folder `dirname` after creating it if necessary :

```
dirname = "somedir"
Dir.mkdir(dirname) unless Dir.exist?(dirname)
dir = Dir.new(dirname)
```

Comment: That's it, sorry for my bad explanaition. The aim was to create an instance of the Dir class. So what I have to do? I don't get it, sorry

Comment: I've looked up in Ruby Docs and it says: 
new( string ) → aDir

Returns a new directory object for the named directory.

Comment: What is your goal? You can only create an instance of a Dir if the corresponding directory exists. What would be the point of referencing a non-existing directory?

Comment: Okay, now I've got it. I'm just following intructions from a book, don't know quite well what is all about, was because I haven't any directory, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In general, whenever a computer is telling you that something doesn't exist, they are usually right. The three main reasons are:

1. The thing truly doesn't exist.
2. The thing does exist, but under another name.
3. The thing does exist, but not where you told the computer to look for it.

I this particular case, you are asking the computer to open a directory named `somedir` inside the current working directory.

So, in order to debug your problem, you should make sure that:

1. The directory `somedir` *really* does exist.
2. The directory is *really* called `somedir`, and not something else (maybe you mistyped its name, maybe it has a file extensions that your file manager is hiding from you by default, maybe it has unprintable characters in its name). Also, make sure it is a directory and not a regular file.
3. The directory *really* is in the program's current working directory. (In particular, a common error mistake is that the current working directory is not what you think it is; remember the current working directory at startup is under complete control of the user, the program has no control over it!)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a directory, you may use the FileUtils module.

First use

```
require 'fileutils'
```

to add the functionalities of the module to your program.

Then you may use

```
FileUtils.mkdir('directory_name')
```

You may even create directories recursively using

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p('parent_directory/child_directory')
```

where `parent_directory` doesn't need to exist, because the `#mkdir_p` acts like `mkdir -p` command and creates the whole structure when needed.